# How do I disable version parsing in cabal or stack?

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack, version-numbering

I am using [alternative version numbering approach](https://www.dropbox.com/s/66ucaf2auolq38u/branches%20naming%20.jpg?dl=0) for my projects. I have encountered strange behavior by `cabal` and `stack` that does not allow me to fully enjoy benefits of this approach. Both `cabal` and `stack` enforce version to be of format `Int`.`Int`.`Int`, which does not cover the case of another version format I use for branches (`0.x.x`, `1.x.x`, `1.0.x`, etc).

If I have line `version: 0.x.x` in my `.cabal` file, I am getting `Parse of field 'version' failed.` error when running `cabal build` or `Unable to parse cabal file {PROJECT_NAME}.cabal: NoParse "version" 5` when running `stack init`.

Is there a way to disable version parsing on `cabal` and `stack` commands? Is there a flag for it? Or do I have to request this kind of change (adding flags, disabling version parsing) from the developers of `cabal` and `stack`?

Why is there any parsing at all? How does it help with building a package? Does `cabal` or `stack` automatically increment build numbers on some event? If yes, where could I read more about this? How could I influence the way version numbering incrementation gets implemented in `cabal` and `stack`? I want developers of haskell packages take into account the possibility of alternative version numbering approaches.

PS. For all interested folks, I want to quickly summarize **the idea behind "weird" version numbers**, such as `0.x.x`, `1.x.x`, `1.0.x`. I use the version numbers with `x`'s to describe streamlines of development that allow code changes while such version numbers as `1.0.0`, `1.1.0`, `2.35.46` are used to describe frozen states of development (to be precise, they are used for *released* versions of software). Note that such version numbers as `0.x.0`, `1.x.15`, `2.x.23` are also possible (used for *snapshots/builds* of software) and they mean that codebase has been inherited from branches with version numbers `0.x.x`, `1.x.x` and `2.x.x` correspondingly.

Why do I need such version numbers as `0.x.x`, `1.x.x` and `2.x.x` at all? In brief, different number of `x`'s mean branches of different types. For example, version number pattern `N.x.x` is used for *support* branches, while pattern `N.M.x` is used for *release* branches. Idea behind *support* branches is that they get created due to incompatibility of the corresponding codebases. *Release* branches get created due to feature freeze in corresponding codebase. For example, branches `1.0.x`, `1.1.x`, `1.2.x`, ... get created as a result of feature freezes (or *releases*) in branch `1.x.x`.

I know this is all confusing, but I worked hard to establish this version numbering approach and I continue working on awareness about the inconsistencies of version numbering through my presentations and other projects. This all makes sense once you think more about the [pitfalls of semver approach](https://www.slideshare.net/altern/agile-software-configuration-management-10042528) (you can find detailed slideshare presentation on the matter following the link). But I do not want to defend it for now. For the time being, I just want `cabal` and `stack` to stop enforcing their, as I perceive them, *unjustified* rules to my project. Hope you can help me with that.

Comment: Why don't you include the image as actual image in your post?

Comment: Just to get it right: the `x` in `1.x.x` isn't a placeholder, you're actually using an `x` in your version?

Comment: @Zeta: yes, I am using 1.x.x as an actual version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to disable version parsing on cabal and stack commands? Is there a flag for it?

No.

> Or do I have to request this kind of change (adding flags, disabling version parsing) from the developers of `cabal` and `stack`?

You can of course ask, but there are so many [outstanding](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues) [issues](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/) that you are unlikely to get any traction. You will have to be *very* convincing -- convincing enough to overturn more than 20 years of experience that says the current versioning scheme is basically workable. Realistically, if you want this to happen you'll probably have to maintain a fork of these tools yourself, and provide an alternative place to host packages using this scheme.

> Why is there any parsing at all? How does it help with building a package?

Packages specify dependencies, and for each dependency, specify what version ranges they work with. The build tools then use a constraint solver to choose a coherent set of package/version pairs to satisfy all the (transitive) dependencies. To do this, they must at a minimum be able to check whether a given version is in a given range -- which requires parsing the version number at least a little bit.

> Does cabal or stack automatically increment build numbers on some event? If yes, where could I read more about this?

There is nothing automatic. But you should take a look at the [Package Version Policy](https://pvp.haskell.org/), which serves as a social contract between package maintainers. It lets one package maintainer say, "I am using `bytestring` version `0.10.0.1` and it seems to work. I'm being careful about qualifying all my `bytestring` imports; therefore I can specify a range like `>=0.10 && <0.11` and be sure that things will just work, while giving the `bytestring` maintainer the ability to push security and efficiency updates to my users." without having to pore through the full documentation of `bytestring` and hope its maintainer had written about what his version numbers mean.

> How could I influence the way version numbering incrementation gets implemented in cabal and stack?

As with your previous question about changing the way the community does things, I think modifications to the Package Versioning Policy are going to be quite difficult, especially changes as radical as you seem to be proposing here. The more radical the change, the more carefully motivated it will have to be to gain traction.

I honestly don't know what a reasonable place to take such motivation and discussion would be; perhaps the haskell-cafe mailing list or similar.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The version will be parsed to `Version`, [which is](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/blob/master/Cabal/Distribution/Version.hs#L111-L118):

```
data Version = PV0 {-# UNPACK #-} !Word64
             | PV1 !Int [Int]
```

Stack uses Cabal as a library [but has its own `Version` type:](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/blob/master/src/Stack/Types/Version.hs#L61-L64)

```
newtype Version =
  Version {unVersion :: Vector Word}
  deriving (Eq,Ord,Typeable,Data,Generic,Store,NFData)
```

Neither cabal nor stack have a way to customize the parsing. You have to write your own variant of those programs if you want to use another version type. But then again, you're not winning anything at that point: neither Hackage nor Stackage will recognize your package's version.

So the `1.x.x` isn't possible at the moment. You could exchange `x` with `99999999` or something similar to mitigate the problem. That being said, it's not clear what `cabal install` should then install. The `99999999` version? Or the latest stable variant?

If you can express the semantics, a discussion on the mailing list as well as a feature request might change the behaviour in the (far away) future, but for now, you either have to patch the programs yourself or use another numbering scheme.